# 2N2222 experiment is indicating incorrect gains

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, 5v, 7805

Okay, so I put a 20kΩ resistor between a 5V supply and the *base* of a 2N2222 with the *collector* connected directly to the 5V rail and *emitter* to ground. What I'd expect is that, roughly, 220μA (i.e. (5V-0.6V)/20kΩ) goes into the base and less than 22mA (i.e. 220μA*100) comes out of the emitter. This isn't what happens at all. I tend to get over 45mA coming out of the emitter.

First, I thought it was my resistor precision. I checked and the actual resistor value is 20.2kΩ (0.1Ω resolution).

I thought it might be the specific transistor but I tried two other 2N2222's. The first was from Mouser and the second two from China. All give roughly the same result.

I then thought maybe it was because I'm using a noisy buck converter. I switched to a linear regulator that gives 4.999V stable for several volts over the +1.6V.

I checked the circuit in CircuitLab using the exact values of my configuration and it gives me what you'd expect: 215.0μA in to the base and 23.17mA out of the emitter.

What's going on? Is this happening because I have no load? Is it because I'm doing this on a breadbord? Do I need capacative decoupling/bypass? Or do I seriously have 3 broken/fake transistors where one of them came from Mouser? If so, why are they all giving the same output?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUK5jC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Which part of "somewhere between 35 and 300" doesn't match your observations?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that a real physical 2N2222's gain is precisely and repeatably 100?

Comment: Congratulations, Anthony, you're measuring the actual gain (under these conditions) of each individual 2N2222. Note that the datasheet only specifies a minimum gain, and the conditions under which it has been tested.

Comment: @brhans : from simulation ;-)

Comment: I didn't think it would be exactly 100 but I thought it would be around or below it. I read the datasheet wrong, switching Ic with Ib (see the first line for hfe: I was thinking around 0.1mA on Ib would produce a gain of 35.) On top of that, I trusted the simulation to know better and it made sense to me (thinking "it's lower, so that makes sense" based on my misreading of the datasheet.)

Comment: Suppose that the simulation did "know better". How would that manifest itself? It would need some sort of "production simulation" mode whereby it simulates a given number of instances of the circuit, with randomized parameters for all the components within their ranges.  "Simulation Fuzzing".  That would be useful for detecting designs that are too sensitive to component values.

Comment: @Kaz: Monte Carlo analyses like the one you're describing are pretty easy to set up in LTSpice: http://k6jca.blogspot.ca/2012/07/monte-carlo-and-worst-case-circuit.html. The default distribution is flat, but the comments on that blog post describe setting it up for Gaussian.

Comment: In a real world design, the *minimum* beta is likely to be the worst case, so that's usually what you want to simulate. In a practical circuit you can easily reduce the gain to a well-defined value using negative feedback, but you can't *increase* gain that doesn't exist!

Comment: Thanks alephzero. That's the right answer as I figured out later last night.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a snippet from the [Fairchild datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/PN/PN2222A.pdf) for the 2N2222.

[image]

As you can see, the h_FE (beta) is highly variable, ranging from 35 (at low temperature) up to a maximum of 300. So, the gain you're measuring is well within limits.

This is not unusual for a BJT - the current gain of these devices varies wildly from lot-to-lot and with temperature. This is why most BJT-based amplifiers implement some type of feedback to remove the dependence on h_fe at the expense of gain.

Comment: (+1) Especially for highlighting the *wild* variation from lot to lot. This is often understated even in university courses and books. They almost always introduce BJTs presenting the classic common emitter amp with NO feedback, which is practically an useless circuit in most situations. The only book I've read that actually points out this fact *from the beginning* is [The Art of Electronics, from Horowitz and Hill](http://artofelectronics.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Hfe or Beta is manufactured with a range of max:min over a 4:1 range and often binned to 2:1 ranges with suffix letter. This is at one test condition only and not limited to the dynamic changes in hFe with other parameters.

> Getting hFE 200 when you expected 100 is unrealistic.
>   Read the datasheet and look for Min Typ and max  200 is normal.

[image]